# Use OpenCV matrix for OpenGL ES texture

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am trying to write an AR application, so far I've used opencv for image warping and things, but warping video frames one by one is computationally expensive. Therefore I am trying to migrate to opengl for augmentation.

So far I tried to get camera frame data, convert it to opencv matrix in java part, and then create a texture from it in the native code. It kinda works, but there are some strange marks in the result : 
[image]

as @Micka suggested , here is my code snippet:

java part :

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera arg1) {
    mFrame.put(0, 0, frame);
    processFrame(mFrame.getNativeObjAddr());
}
```

native part :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_..._CameraPreviewer_processFrame( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jlong addr)
    cv::Mat& mFrame = *(cv::Mat*)addr;
    cv::cvtColor(mFrame, buffer[(bI) % 30], cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21);
}
```

and onDrawFrame Renderer (native):

```
{
    ...
    cvtColor(buffer[(bI) % 30], frame, CV_BGR2BGR565);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (1024-frameWidth)/2, (1024-frameHeight)/2, frameWidth, frameHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, frame.ptr());
    ...
}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: so how can i make these lines disappeared ?

Comment: do both, opengl and opencv use the same data layout? can you post (relevant parts of) your code?